# NTML Mediator - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm trying to use in built NTML Mediator. All I do is create an empty proxy service and paste code from example here: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/mediators/ntlm-mediator/

When I try to run this service I get following error:

```
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,616]  INFO {NTLMMediator} - [NTLMMediator] Init method Invoked.
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,618] ERROR {AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} - Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1696942987593TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\NTLMTestProxy_1.0.0\NTLMTestProxy-1.0.0.xml : Failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.NTLMMediator.init(NTLMMediator.java:244)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.init(AbstractListMediator.java:203)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:296)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.initializeProxy(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:271)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:205)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1129)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:139)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:189)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:227)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jcifs.Config cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 78 more

[2023-10-10 15:03:07,618]  INFO {AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} - The file has been backed up into : NO_BACKUP_ON_WORKER.INFO
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,619] ERROR {AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} - Deployment of synapse artifact failed. Error reading C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1696942987593TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\NTLMTestProxy_1.0.0\NTLMTestProxy-1.0.0.xml : jcifs/Config org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:215)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1129)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:139)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:189)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:227)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.NTLMMediator.init(NTLMMediator.java:244)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.init(AbstractListMediator.java:203)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:296)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.initializeProxy(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:271)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:205)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jcifs.Config cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 78 more

[2023-10-10 15:03:07,619] ERROR {CappDeployer} - Error occurred while deploying the Carbon application: TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car. Reverting successfully deployed artifacts in the CApp. org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:227)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1129)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:139)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:189)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:227)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:215)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.NTLMMediator.init(NTLMMediator.java:244)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.init(AbstractListMediator.java:203)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:296)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.initializeProxy(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:271)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:205)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jcifs.Config cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 78 more

[2023-10-10 15:03:07,619]  INFO {CappDeployer} - Undeploying Carbon Application : NTLMTestCompositeExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT...
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,625]  INFO {CappDeployer} - Successfully undeployed Carbon Application : NTLMTestCompositeExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT{super-tenant}
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,626]  INFO {AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Dashboard is configured. Initiating heartbeat component.
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,648]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8290
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,651]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8253
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,652]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 4,93 seconds
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,711]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9201
[2023-10-10 15:03:07,718]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
[2023-10-10 15:03:09,254]  INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
```

When I delete mediator it runs fine. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the JCIFS dependency to the lib directory. You can download it from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codelibs/jcifs/2.1.9/).

Comment: Now I'm getting error:
[2023-10-10 18:03:43,040] ERROR {CappDeployer} - Error occurred while deploying the Carbon application: TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car. Reverting successfully deployed artifacts in the CApp. org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: 'java.lang.Object jcifs.Config.setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Comment: @idix Try adding this dependency. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs.wso2/jcifs/1.3.17.wso2v1 make sure you delete the old jar from both lib and droppings directory.